# Dirac Delta Representation in terms of Bessel Y

Tags: dirac-delta, bessel-functions

On the wikipedia page for the Hankel transform, one finds the identity
$$
\int_0^\infty r J_{\nu}(k r) J_{\nu}(k'r) = \frac{\delta(k-k')}{k} 
$$
where $J_\nu$ is the Bessel function.vMy question is there a related statement for Bessel Functions of the second kind $Y_{\nu}$? Something like
$$
\int_0^\infty r Y_{\nu}(k r) Y_{\nu}(k'r) dr = \frac{\delta(k-k')}{k} ?
$$